# Can we apply boost::fusion::transform on a random access sequence generated by adapting a class?

Tags: c++, boost

Can we apply boost::fusion::transform on a random access sequence generated by adapting a class?

I have a class holding vector of another class types. I adapted the former class into a sequence using BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT macro which generates a random sequence. But in the boost documentation for transform, i saw that the sequence should be a forward sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Random access sequences *are* forward sequences. Just like random access iterators in the C++ standard library are also forward iterators.

The similar terminology is not an accident.

Comment: I get errors regarding "result" being not a class or function template and not a base class etc.., in resultof.hpp

Comment: @Anu: Your question was whether `transform` takes random access sequences. I answered that. It seems like your question *really* was "why doesn't my code work". That's a completely different question, which you are invited to ask with the "Ask Question" button. This time, please provide your actual code.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fe37783bb484b1f the code link.. there's a thread for the same problem.. but i want to see things through my view..

Comment: I think the code is not compiling fine witg msvc but is fine for other compilers like gcc, etc as in coliru, code is working fine. Im going crazy!

Comment: @Anu: Perhaps you didn't get the "subtle" hit to post this as a new question. This is not a forum. You ask a question about X, and we provide an answer about X. If that didn't actually fix your problem Y, then you need to ask a question about Y. Posting a comment about Y is not helpful.